# How to extend more than one class using Swift 4/5

Tags: ios, swift, class, uikit

I am trying to extend more than one class which are UIButton and UITextField. They both have the same function where they can wiggle when I call the function. I'm trying not to repeat my code more than once. I have been attempting to use protocal that I can extend the and write the function that I want and then extend them in my classes, but the problem is in my function I have to call self, but I will get an error since self can be only called on UITextField and UIButton.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

extension UIButton {

    func wiggle() {
        let position = "position"
        let wiggleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: position)
        wiggleAnimation.duration = 0.05
        wiggleAnimation.repeatCount = 5
        wiggleAnimation.autoreverses = true
        wiggleAnimation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        wiggleAnimation.toValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        layer.add(wiggleAnimation, forKey: position)
    }

}

extension UITextField {

    func wiggle() {
        let position = "position"
        let wiggleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: position)
        wiggleAnimation.duration = 0.05
        wiggleAnimation.repeatCount = 5
        wiggleAnimation.autoreverses = true
        wiggleAnimation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        wiggleAnimation.toValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        layer.add(wiggleAnimation, forKey: position)
    }

}
```

Here is what I have tried to attempt but I get an error because I am calling self.

```
protocol Animations {
    func wiggle()
}

extension Animations {
    func wiggle() {
        let position = "position"
        let wiggleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: position)
        wiggleAnimation.duration = 0.05
        wiggleAnimation.repeatCount = 5
        wiggleAnimation.autoreverses = true
        wiggleAnimation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        wiggleAnimation.toValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        layer.add(wiggleAnimation, forKey: position)
    }
}

extension UIButton: Animations {}

extension UITextField: Animations {}
```

The errors that I receive are 
Value of type 'Self' has no member 'center'
Value of type 'Self' has no member 'center'
Use of unresolved identifier 'layer'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answer given does not actually compile using Swift 4.x, as protocols could not directly inherit from classes before Swift 5.

The correct way to write this in Swift 4.x involves providing a default implementation for your `wiggle()` function only when the conforming type inherits from `UIView`. The correct way to write this is:

```
protocol Animations {
    func wiggle()
}
extension Animations where Self: UIView {
   func wiggle() {
        let position = "position"
        let wiggleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: position)
        wiggleAnimation.duration = 0.05
        wiggleAnimation.repeatCount = 5
        wiggleAnimation.autoreverses = true
        wiggleAnimation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        wiggleAnimation.toValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        layer.add(wiggleAnimation, forKey: position)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you extend the UIButton class or other classes?

Comment: if you write the protocol as above, you would simply extend any `UIView` inheriting class to conform to it.

So you would write
`extension UIButton: Animations {} `

Answer (score 6):

Only `UIView` has a center property. Your protocol declaration should look like this for Swift 5+:

```
protocol Animations: UIView {
    func wiggle()
}
```

Care that only UIViews can conform to this protocol.

For Swift 4.x you have to use it like this:

```
protocol Animations {
    func wiggle()
}

extension Animations where Self: UIView {
   func wiggle() {
        let position = "position"
        let wiggleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: position)
        wiggleAnimation.duration = 0.05
        wiggleAnimation.repeatCount = 5
        wiggleAnimation.autoreverses = true
        wiggleAnimation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        wiggleAnimation.toValue = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 4.0, y: self.center.y)
        layer.add(wiggleAnimation, forKey: position)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI this answer is for Swift 5+ only

Comment: @erdos I edited my answer and added the Swift 4.x verison. Thank you for the hint.